# TableSorter + Filter > tskeyCodes = undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, tablesorter

I've downloaded the latest version of TableSorter and the filter widget.

Unfortunately the filters are not working. The error when I apply a filter is: 
['Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enter' of undefined'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXjMj.png). When I debug the debugger says [tskeyCodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8myA.png) is undefined.

I apply the scripts in a MVC Azure Application.

The script of the table sorter looks like this:

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
        widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_cssFilter: '',

            filter_childRows: false,
            filter_hideFilters: false,
            filter_ignoreCase: true,
            filter_saveFilters: true,
            filter_searchDelay: 300,
            filter_startsWith: false,
            filter_hideFilters: false,

            filter_external: 'input.search',
            filter_reset: '.reset',
            filter_functions: {
                // Add select menu to this column
                0: true,
                1: true,
                4: true
            },
       }
    });
```

This behavior is present in Chrome as well as in IE.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does tsKeyCodes come from?

Comment: `tsKeyCodes` is a variable that points to `$.tablesorter.keyCodes` ([ref](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js#L193)) in my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/)... please make sure you are using the most up-to-date tablesorter from that fork and not the original tablesorter.

Comment: Maybe that was the problem Mottie. I changed the separate references to javascripts ('jquery.tablesorter.js' and 'jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js') to the combined one ('jquery.tablesorter.combined.js') and it started working.